# Cleaner Power Spectra with SciPy Fast Fourier Transform?

Tags: scipy, fft, physics

I have thousands of time series to generate power spectra for. I am using SciPy FFT. The results I have gotten are generally good--there are peaks in the right places. But they are "jagged"--immediately before each peak, a small valley appears (see picture).

Power spectra: Frequency on x axis, power on right. The peaks are in the right places, but there's a small valley right before the peak which should not be there.

[image: Power spectra: Frequency on x axis, power on right. The peaks are in the right places, but there's a small valley right before the peak which should not be there.]

This project requires plotting the real component of the FFT instead of its absolute value.

I've tried changing up time granularity of the signal with varying success. Any experts know how to consistently give clean, accurate spectra?

Full code and info:
This is a double pendulum. Theta is the angle of the top arm from the vertical, phi is the angle of the bottom arm from the vertical. Equal lengths, equal masses, dimensionless units. They are summarized in the system of differential equations.

```py
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
def dtr(degrees):
  return (degrees/360)*(2*np.pi)

stoptime_main = 204.8
interval_main = 0.01


def eqs(t, w):
    z, y, m, n = w
# Theta is represented by z. Phi is represented by y. Momentum in theta 
# (top) is represented by m. Momentum in phi (bottom) is represented by n.  

    f = [
         (m - (n * np.cos(z - y))) / (1 + (np.sin(z - y)) ** 2), 
         ((2*n) - (m * np.cos(z - y))) / (1 + (np.sin(z - y)) ** 2), 
         (-2 * np.sin(z)) - ((m * n * np.sin(z - y)) / (1 + (np.sin(z - y)) ** 2)) + ((((m**2) + (2*(n**2)) - (2*m*n*np.cos(z - y))) * np.sin(2*(z - y))) / (2 * ((1 + (np.sin(z - y)) ** 2) ** 2))),
         (-1 * np.sin(y)) + ((m * n * np.sin(z - y)) / (1 + (np.sin(z - y)) ** 2)) - ((((m**2) + (2*(n**2)) - (2*m*n*np.cos(z - y))) * np.sin(2*(z - y))) / (2 * ((1 + (np.sin(z - y)) ** 2) ** 2)))
    ]

    return f
def rungekutta8(theta, phi):
    z1 = theta
    y1 = phi
    m1 = 0
    n1 = 0

    abserr = 1.0e-8
    relerr = 1.0e-6
    stoptime = stoptime_main
    interval = interval_main

    t = np.arange(0.0, stoptime, interval)
    t_span = (0.0, stoptime)

    p = []
    w0 = [z1, y1, m1, n1]

    wsol = solve_ivp(eqs, t_span, w0, t_eval=t, method='DOP853')
    
    return wsol, t 

wsol, t = rungekutta8(dtr(32), dtr(0))
z_list = wsol.y[0, :]
y_list = wsol.y[1, :]
m_list = wsol.y[2, :]
n_list = wsol.y[3, :]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq

def decompose_signal(x, time):
    # Calculate the Fourier Transform
    fft_vals = fft(x)
    
    # Calculate the frequencies corresponding to the Fourier Transform
    n = len(x)
    timestep = time[1] - time[0]
    freq_resolution = 1 / (n * timestep)
    frequencies = fftfreq(n, d=timestep)[:n//2]
    
    # Filter frequencies and FFT values to range from 0 to 3 Hz
    mask = (frequencies >= 0) & (frequencies <= 3)
    frequencies = frequencies[mask]
    fft_vals = fft_vals[:n//2][mask]
    
    # Generate higher resolution frequencies
    higher_resolution_frequencies = np.linspace(0, 3, 50000)
    
    # Interpolate the FFT values to match the higher resolution frequencies
    interpolated_fft_vals = np.interp(higher_resolution_frequencies, frequencies, fft_vals)
    
#     return higher_resolution_frequencies, np.abs(interpolated_fft_vals)
    return frequencies, np.abs(fft_vals), fft_vals

frequencies, abs_value, real_comp = decompose_signal(z_list, t)
plt.plot(frequencies, real_comp)
plt.xlim([0, 0.8])
```

Comment: Just edited to add the code. This project requires plotting the real component of the FFT. The absolute value generally gives a cleaner plot, though.

Comment: Having to plot the real component is a bit of an odd requirement here, that way you're not plotting power: power depends on the magnitude

Comment: Surely. We're less interested in the actual power and more interested in the frequencies that have local maxima. The real component is necessary to make some of our analysis work.

Comment: The spectra are already both "clean" and "accurate". If you don't like the fact that there are negative real values, then you need to re-examine the data that your Runge-Kutta routine is generating. There are other issues with the way that you're performing your FFT, but those are not responsible for the negative valleys.

Comment: Also, there's a decent chance that you don't want the apparent peak frequency here, but the zero-crossing frequency. This misinterpretation actually _would_ lead to inaccuracy.

Comment: @pmc1303 what is the expression for the expected peak frequency? With this knowledge, using timeseries trimming you can increase the accuracy

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `dtr` and use `np.deg2rad`.

Don't make a frequency mask - for your cutoff, calculate the index based on the frequency, timestep and length.

Don't call `fft`; call `rfft`. Don't slice by `[:n//2]`.

Don't interpolate (you haven't shown any code that justifies it).

For clarity, when you plot, plot the phase, real, imaginary and absolute components. If and when you do peak-finding, you almost certainly should not consume the real component, but instead the absolute.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.integrate._ivp.ivp import OdeResult


def eqs(t: float, w: np.ndarray) -> tuple[float, float, float, float]:
    z, y, m, n = w
    # Theta is represented by z. Phi is represented by y. Momentum in theta
    # (top) is represented by m. Momentum in phi (bottom) is represented by n.

    f = (
        (m - n*np.cos(z - y)) / (1 + np.sin(z - y)**2),

        (2*n - m*np.cos(z - y)) / (1 + np.sin(z - y)**2),

        -2*np.sin(z)
        - m*n*np.sin(z - y) / (1 + (np.sin(z - y))**2)
        + (
            (m**2 + 2*n**2 - 2*m*n*np.cos(z - y)) * np.sin(2*(z - y))
            / (2 * ((1 + (np.sin(z - y))**2)**2))
        ),

        -np.sin(y)
        + m*n*np.sin(z - y) / (1 + np.sin(z - y)**2)
        - (
            (m**2 + 2*n**2 - 2*m*n*np.cos(z - y)) * np.sin(2*(z - y))
            / (2 * ((1 + (np.sin(z - y))**2)**2))
        ),
    )

    return f


def rungekutta8(
    theta: float, phi: float, stoptime: float, interval: float,
) -> tuple[
    OdeResult,   # w solution
    np.ndarray,  # time series
]:
    z1 = theta
    y1 = phi
    m1 = 0
    n1 = 0

    t = np.arange(0, stoptime, interval)
    wsol = solve_ivp(
        fun=eqs,
        t_span=(0, stoptime),
        y0=(z1, y1, m1, n1),
        t_eval=t,
        method='DOP853',
    )

    return wsol, t


def decompose_signal(x: np.ndarray, time: np.ndarray, cutoff: float) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # frequencies
    np.ndarray,  # complex spectrum
]:
    fft_vals = rfft(x, norm='forward')
    n = len(x)
    timestep = time[1] - time[0]
    freqs = rfftfreq(n=n, d=timestep)
    cutoff_idx = round(n * timestep * cutoff)
    return freqs[:cutoff_idx], fft_vals[:cutoff_idx]


def main() -> None:
    wsol, t = rungekutta8(
        theta=np.deg2rad(32), phi=0, stoptime=204.8, interval=0.01,
    )
    z_list, y_list, m_list, n_list = wsol.y
    freqs, spectrum = decompose_signal(z_list, t, cutoff=0.4)

    ax_amp: plt.Axes
    ax_phase: plt.Axes
    fig, (ax_amp, ax_phase) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

    ax_amp.plot(freqs, np.abs(spectrum), label='|z|')
    ax_amp.plot(freqs, np.real(spectrum), label='Re(z)')
    ax_amp.plot(freqs, np.imag(spectrum), label='Im(z)')
    ax_amp.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    ax_amp.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
    ax_amp.grid(visible=True, which='major', axis='both', color='#ddd')
    ax_amp.legend()

    ax_phase.plot(freqs, np.rad2deg(np.angle(spectrum)), label='arg(z)')
    ax_phase.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    ax_phase.set_ylabel('Phase (deg)')
    ax_phase.set_yticks(np.arange(-180, 181, 45))
    ax_phase.grid(visible=True, which='major', axis='both', color='#ddd')

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: spectral plots]